# How to prevent the user from leaving my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make an online test using spring-mvc and html, css, jquery and I want to prevent the user that is doing the test from leave the test screen while doing the test. Does anybody know how I can do that?

Comment: since it's from a web browser, no you cant. the user can make new tabs. close the browser and do many other things.

Comment: **disable the user to leave my screen** please elaborate it. Do you mean by closing browser window OR just switch the window OR minimize the window?

Comment: Write your test in an .exe instead of a browser if you want to know what they're up-to.  Won't stop them using 2nd PC/mobile phone to get your answers though...

Comment: If this was possible, do you not think spammers/hackers/advertisers would have already done this to your browser and you wouldn't even be able to have posted this question.

Comment: @freedomn-m They did, big time until the browser makers made it harder/impossible

Comment: There are so many ways this can be done. So no you just can prevent them 100%. You can alert them at some point though.

Comment: disable the user to leave my screen - it doesn't need to be necessarily disable (because that can't be done), but i want to somehow warn the user when he tries to switch the focus from the test screen. Can that be done?